# INetC::get from ftp location does not show download percentage

Tags: ftp, installation, nsis

```
INetC::get "ftp://user:password@ftp.aaa.com/bbb/ccc.exe" "$INSTDIR/bbb/ccc.exe" /end
```

I am using the above script to download file from ftp location. Progress bar does not show total size of the file and it will always display 0% of 0KB.
(**646kB(0%) of 0kB @ 894.8kB/s**) any ideas how to show the correct file size and correct percentage.

BTW if I do the download from dropbox location it will display correct values.

`Update`

**Wireshark trace:**

```
SIZE bbb/ccc.exe
550 SIZE not allowed in ASCII mode
TYPE I
200 Type set to I
PASV
227 Entering passive mode(192,**,***,**,221,185).
SIZE bbb/ccc.exe
213 50225880
RETR bbb/ccc.exe  
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for bbb/ccc.exe (50225880)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the URL of the real FTP server would help, there is no way to diagnose this without access to the server.

I know the plugin implements some workarounds for broken servers but I guess it does not always work.

The plugin uses the WinInet library and should display progress-bars in the same places as Internet Explorer. It worked for me on the few servers I tried:

```
InitPluginsDir
INetC::get "ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/make/make-4.1.tar.gz" "$PluginsDir\test.bin"
Pop $1
DetailPrint $1
```

Comment: I just did a quick test on the ftp URL you provided. It just worked fine. I can not provide the URL here, as it has some confidential information. How can I debug this. I am not that familiar with debugging plugins.

Comment: Can you give me sample test program to debug my issue

Comment: @Vivek You should start by analyzing the traffic with Wireshark, Fiddler or another traffic capture tool and see if there are any clues to why no size information is found. You could perhaps modify the plugin to call FtpGetFileSize if it does not already do so. To actually debug the plugin you will need to install WinDbg and/or Visual Studio and you will probably also have to trace into WinInet itself, all of this requires a fair bit of win32 and debugging knowledge...

Comment: I will start with wireshark

Comment: Please check the update on wireshark trace. Looks like it failed to get size in ASCII mode. any ideas?

Comment: @Vivek The plugin uses ASCII mode when requesting the size, I attached a modified version @ http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=3031772&postcount=517 that you can try. If that does not help we could probably try calling FtpGetFileSize.

Comment: @Vivek I uploaded two new builds to the same post, please try both.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like issue with your server. Is there something special? Maybe this can be set in settings (configuration) of server.

The plug-in is working fine for me (even for you as you write) so I assume there is some hidden catch.

Can you run the installer with debugger attached? You need to debug the plug-in, not NSIS, e. g. in Visual Studio.

That will show you which values plug-in receives as reply from server and could solve the problem.

Comment: How do I debug? I did not get any debug files plugin.

Comment: What settings I need to look on the ftp server?